# autossh exit when using the -f option

Tags: linux, ssh, autossh

When running autossh without the "-f" option, everything works fine.
Adding the "-f" option indeed sends autossh to the background, but after the ssh tunneling established correctly the autossh itself exit, leaving the ssh connection without monitor.

Here is the command I'm running: `autossh -f -M 20000 -N -L 0.0.0.0:5601:10.10.0.8:5601 10.10.0.8`

Anyone knows what can cause this problem? alternatively - anyone knows how can I debug autossh when using the "-f"? (is there any log file produce when using AUTOSSH_DEBUG=1)?

(I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04)

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 3):

On macOS I had a problem where `autossh -M 0 -R 1234:localhost:22` worked but adding `-f` to make autossh run in background would log the following and autossh would die instantly:

```
2018/04/10 12:00:06 autossh[67839]: ssh exited with status 0; autossh exiting
```

Adding `-N` ("Do not execute a remote command.") fixed the issue:

```
autossh -f -M 0 -N -R 1234:localhost:22
```

Seeing you already had `-N` in the command this is probably unrelated but possibly helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as no one has a better suggestion... Try running autossh under a watchdog like [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).  With this method autossh runs as a foreground child of a `supervise` daemon (so, no `-f` switch).  You can start and stop it with the `svc` command, and you can log all of its output with `multilog`.

This method has proven sufficiently reliable for me, on a fleet of production boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. daemontools look like a solid workaround for that problem. For now I used "screen" which also allows me to run it without the "-f", but I think that for production use cases daemontools is the right tool.